# nl2br() not working quite right

Tags: php, mysql, html, textarea

I am using the following to submit a post from a textarea to my mysql database in order to preserve single/double/triple line spacing on the output.:

```
$update = nl2br(htmlentities($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
```

Sometimes it works but sometimes a double is replaced with a single line space and other times double line spaces are preserved.  Here is my output, all of this was input using double line spaces (hitting enter twice).  Any suggestions on how to improve this would be appreciated:

```
    something

    went

    a 
    little

    wrong
    there
```

Thanks Prinzhorn.  Below is the CREATE TABLE statement for the table in question.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ticket_updates` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ticket_id` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `update` text NOT NULL,
  `time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `member_id` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=28 ;
```

Comment: Show the `CREATE TABLE` statement, especially for the column

Comment: maybe you could post the html code too

Comment: good catch - its not the submit its the display! - I want to prevent template bleeding so was using wordwrap($update, 50, "&nbsp;\n", true) - this is not right - but I guess thats a new question with new catagories ;) - thanks guys!

Comment: Fixed my wordwrap issue with CSS3 word-break:break-all; - word-break:break-word; would not work with IE9 - Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was caused by using `wordwrap()` to try and format the output and NOT due to:

```
nl2br(htmlentities($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
```

I changed my `wordwrap($update, 50, "&nbsp;\n", true)` to CSS3 propertey `word-break:break-all;` (`word-break:break-word;` would not work with IE9)

Answer (score 0):

If You use htmlentities() it encodes "\n" to "%5Cn". so, it might get create problem to get the actual output.

Try the following code, might helps you to find, what the actual output you need.

`echo htmlentities($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');`